# SQL Query to DAX (in Power BI) with multiple joins, count, group by

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and am trying to learn DAX after having been exposed to SQL.  I have messed around in Power BI with the Group by function, but am not sure how that works when you have a count in the select statement and multiple joins.  I have also tried the option where you import data from SQL Server and paste this query and that works, but it makes it independent of other data visualizations in Power BI when I add a date slicer from another table.

My goal is to make this query into a pie chart.  Then I would like to have a date slicer for date/PTO date so that you can designate a time frame and the pie chart will update with the correct count by state.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    state,
    Count(ptodate) AS TotalPTO 
FROM
    solar.solar.accounts AS sa 
    JOIN
        solar.solar.systems AS ss 
        ON sa.systemid = ss.systemid 
    JOIN
        solar.solar.addresses AS sad 
        ON sa.addressid = sad.addressid 
    JOIN
        solar.solar.customerassociatedepccalculations AS sepc 
        ON sa.customerid = sepc.customerid 
    JOIN
        solar.reference.merchants AS rm 
        ON sa.merchantid = rm.merchantid 
WHERE
    sepc.active = 1 
    AND rm.merchantid = 4 
GROUP BY
    state;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your particular question is? It's not clear as written.

Comment: How to write the SQL query in DAX language

Comment: DAX can only be used as a query language if your data is stored in a cube (e.g. SQL Server Analysis Service). If your data is in a SQL database, you will have to use SQL to query the data. You can use DAX to create custom measures and column once the data is in Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

So DAX is for calculations to the data after you already have it imported; It's not for querying.

For querying you'd do one of 3 things:

Use the GUI of PowerQuery (i.e. go to 'Get Data' & click through)

Write the M Code yourself (this is a different language than DAX - and honestly not    really worth doing usualy)

**Or just use SQL like you currently are** Get Data > SQL Server >    Advanced Options, and just paste in your query

Comment: Yes, I have tried the Get Data option and pasted my query.  I created a pie chart for it, but when I try to have the date slicer for PTOdate, the pie chart is not updated.  Maybe my data model connecting the query to the other SQL tables isn't correct or I am missing something?

Comment: You'd have to connect the tables in Power BI Model view but...

Looking at your query, you're not producing a date column.  Just a state column, with a count of dates. Since there's no date column produced by that query...so you can't filter by date.  So, unless I'm misunderstanding, maybe you need help with the SQL query first, and not the Power Bi portion?

Comment: I agree with you.  How would I produce a date column?  How can you have any other columns in your query when I am using the aggregate count function and grouping by state? State and count(ptodate) are the only columns I'm producing in the SELECT statement.  How do I produce a date column?  Thanks

Comment: Okay, I have corrected my code and this works now to have a date slicer that updates with the pie chart in Power Bi.  select  state, count(PtoDate) as TotalPTO, ptodate
from 
solar.solar.accounts as sa 
join solar.solar.systems as ss on sa.systemid=ss.systemid
join solar.solar.addresses as sad on sa.addressid = sad.addressid
join solar.solar.CustomerAssociatedEpcCalculations as sepc on sa.customerid =sepc.customerid
join solar.reference.merchants as rm on sa.merchantid =rm.merchantid
where sepc.active =1 and rm.merchantid =4
group by state, ptodate;